# Some questions about String in runtime constant pool or heap？

Tags: java, string, jvm

use JDK1.8

```
//create string s1
String s1 = new String("1")+new String("1");

//native method, put s1 into string constant pool
s1.intern();

//create variable s2  
String s2 = "11";

System.out.println(s1 == s2);
```

Will output true in this code，but if you replace the first line with the following code

```
String s1 = new String("11")+new String("");
```

it will output false

now my doubt is:
When first code run what happened in heap and pool? and the code `intern`

It is best to describe to me how each step changes between the heap and the pool, thank you

Comment: it's best not to compare `Strings` with `==` - use `.equals(...)` instead

Comment: @Ochi, I don't think the poster is curious about what's best practice here, he/she wants to better understand how memory management behind the scenes works, and understand the seemingly inconsistent behavior of the `intern()` function.

Comment: @kshetline I understood the question but comparing strings with `==` can lead to inconsistent results (perhaps like the above?) - so let's start with using best practices and then see how the heap/pool behaves

Comment: In this case if you use best practices you'll never find out what happens behind the scenes, because then you'll be totally shielded from it. Which is of course what you want for real-world code, but it doesn't satisfy any purely intellectual curiosity

Comment: Isn't all of this behind the scenes and subject to change at any point?

Comment: @kshetline you have a valid point.  I will respectfully disagree, however, as I cannot discern if the behaviour above is because of `.intern()` or because of comparing strings with `==`?  I don't know that right now - OP could start with using best practices and see if the behaviour is similar to issue in question.  If so, the question gains more validity (before that, there is another variable to the equation you are trying to solve so you might be chasing after the wrong issue, asking the wrong question)

Comment: As @JimGarrison said this behavior can change in different java version this is not the thing to understand it totally depend on java version.

Comment: @ochi I just use ```==``` to juge the same hash

Comment: @ochi As you said, I tested it, and it is also related to the ```intern()``` method. If the first code removes the ```intern```, it will return false,i can't understand how memory management behind the scenes works

Answer (score 2):

You should read [the documentation of `s1.intern()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern--) carefully:

> Returns a canonical representation for the string object.
>   …
>   When the intern method is invoked, if the pool already contains a string equal to this `String` object as determined by the `equals(Object)` method, then the string from the pool is returned. Otherwise, this `String` object is added to the pool and a reference to this `String` object is returned.

Since the contract is about what the method will *return*, you should not ignore the return value of the method invocation.

Your assumption that `s1.intern();` will “put s1 into string constant pool” is wrong. The method will *return* a string contained in the constant pool, which *may* be the same string, now added to the pool, if there wasn’t a string with the same contents before.

So in your first test, you exhibited an implementation specific behavior of the string being added to the pool, as there was no string with the same contents before.

In contrast, in the second test, it is guaranteed, that the string will not be added to the pool. As the documentation continues:

> All literal strings and string-valued constant expressions are interned. String literals are defined in section 3.10.5 of the *The Java™ Language Specification*.

You already exploited this behavior by comparing the string reference with a reference created for the literal `"11"` appearing after the `intern()` call. But when your code starts with `String s1 = new String("11")+new String("");`, you have a string literal `"11"` *before* the call, which is added to the pool automatically. The expression `new String("11")+new String("")` creates a new `String` instance, not identical to the string literal and not added to the pool, as there is already a string with the same contents.

Which is easy to prove when we actually use the returned value:

```
String s1 = new String("11")+new String("");
String shouldBeInPool = s1.intern();

String s2 = "11";

System.out.println(shouldBeInPool == s2);
```

prints `true`.

Note that your first example

```
String s1 = new String("1")+new String("1");

s1.intern();

String s2 = "11";
System.out.println(s1 == s2);
```

will print `false` on older JDKs, e.g. JDK 6 from Sun.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we create a String Object, two objects will be created i.e. One in the Heap Area and One in the String constant pool and the String object reference always points to heap area object. so new String("11") will be created  One object in the Heap Area,and s1 reference  points to heap. the detail you can visit :https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interning-of-string/, hope you enjoy it!